# auto scroll images in horizontalscrollview android

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have this layout and i want to automatically display three photos in an HorizontalScrollView (from left to right). **What should i do?**

This is my layout code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="387dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView."
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="387dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ad"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="387dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/addd"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/addd"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `Horizontal ScrollView`.

It decides whether the `scrollview` should stretch its content to fill the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if you use imageview in your layout try to use 

  android:src="@drawable/add"

instead of    

android:background="@drawable/add"
```

I hope it will help you.